# body shows white space on the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I put together this website:
[brudenellridingstables.com](http://brudenellridingstables.com)

Based off this template - 
https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/

The issue I'm having is that there is a white space on the right side of the page.

I have tried

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and this fixes the white space issue **BUT** the **overflow-x: hidden;** line breaks the before/after behavior of the navbar and causes the fa icons further down the page to not show.

Is there I way I can have both the functionality of the navbar AND the fa icons while controlling the overflow-x of the body of the page?

Or is there something else I can do in the CSS to fix this?

I'm not very knowledgeable on the parent child dynamics in CSS, is there perhaps something going on besides the overflow-x that is causing the white space on the right?

I have seen this question a few times but not with a navbar like mine.  I think it would be helpful to others to have these questions answered as it would further their knowledge of the intricacies of CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: Not seeing the white-space in chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: the issue has mostly been fixed now thanks to a) me staring at the code and asking "OK, so why don't ALL the sections have the white space? What makes them different?" then b) me seeing that the other sections are in a .container or a .container-fluid and then c) my thought process being confirmed by  @MichaelCoker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a section in the middle of the page (after `header`) with `class="row bg-primary"`

A `.row` needs to be in a `.container` or `.container-fluid`. What you're seeing is the `-15px` left/right `margin` on `.row`, which is normally offset by a `.container` parent.

Wrap that row in `.container-fluid`.

Comment: I was about to write the same. You are not using the bootstrap semantic way to create a template, so thats why it breaks your design.

Comment: +1 `.row {
 margin-right:0;
}` is a start to understand where this extra gap comes from ;)